# Alternative to using namespace as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

I know I cannot use a namespace as a template parameter. However, I'm trying to achieve behavior similar to this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T::X* x)
{
    T::bar(x);
}
```

Except T is a namespace rather than a struct or a class. What is the best way to achieve the most similar result to what I am expecting?

Comment: Is that the only thing you want to do? Because you could use a macro... :)

Comment: It would be better if you show: how you want to use this template; instead showing: how you think it should be written. It may turn out that @StoryTeller answer doesn't match your requirements, but it is a valid fix for code you've provided.

Comment: Is it the case that most namespaces contain function templates and/or functions that accept arguments from same and other namespaces named "bar"? Did the authors ran out of verbs? Note that the very situation is confusing for human reader. That can indeed be made unambiguous for C++ compiler by using parentheses around function name to pick from same namespace or helper namespaces to pick from argument namespace but it is smelly anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Except T is a namespace rather than a struct or a class. What is the best way to achieve the most similar result to what I am expecting?

Don't mention `T` at all.

```
template <typename X>
void foo(X* x)
{
    bar(x);
}
```

[ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) will always pick up on overloads from the namespace where `X` is defined. Let the mechanism do its work.

---

Now, if you are asking how to make the compiler *favor* functions found by ADL, it's all about manipulating overload resolution. We can do that by limiting what is picked up by regular unqualified name lookup:

```
namespace foo_detail {
    void bar(...);
    template<typename X>
    void foo_impl(X* x) {
        bar(x);
    }
}

template <typename X>
void foo(X* x)
{
    foo_detail::foo_impl(x);
}
```

When the call in `foo_detail::foo_impl` is trying to resolve `bar`, the first phase in two-phase lookup will pickup the C variable argument function. Now lookup stops, no further enclosing namespaces will be looked in. Which means that only ADL can offer more candidates. And due to how overload resolution works, a C-style variable argument function like we added will be a worse match than anything ADL will find.

Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/506f0f41dfa59390) for all of this at work.

Comment: Hahaha :) lol but this won't work if there is a `bar` already in `foo`'s namespace, which is why I'm assuming OP wanted to call it with namespace qualifier.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - There are ways to address that too (I know you know) :) If the OP has a case like that on their hands, it sounds to me like prime material for a followup question.

Comment: Hmm I know the reverse (no ADL) but not how to disable unqual lookup and only get ADL.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - regular unqualified name lookup up namespace scopes stops the moment a name is found. So if one adds a layer of indirection, where only the worst possible match may be found... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08e1f9d97ed4bb97

Comment: Thanks so much! Does exactly what I wanted. Was not familiar enough with the ADL rules. Guess you learn something new every day :)

Comment: @Oracular - Happy to be of help :)

Comment: @StoryTeller what if the function bar() does not take a parameter based on the template type? What if it is just bar(int) or something similar?

Comment: @Oracular - For ADL to work, the argument must be a user-defined type. That did not look like a possibility in your original post however. I suppose your `X` is a type alias? There is no solution for it to my knowledge, short of doing what Marek proposed, and using a `struct` in lieu of a namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Namespace can't be a template parameter.
The only possible template parameters are:

- types
- and values which are: [Template parameters and template arguments - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter)

> - [std::nullptr_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) (since C++11);
> - an [integral type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type);
> - a [pointer type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) (to object or to function);
> - a [pointer to member type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members) (to member object or to member function);
> - an [enumeration type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

So if you want change `bar` version depending on namespace it can't be done like you proposed.
It can be achieved if `bar` is enclosed in class as a static function. In such case you can use your template, then that class becomes template parameter.

So your code can look lie this:

```
class Variant1 {
public:
    typedef int* argType;

    static void bar(argType i) {
        std::cout << (*i + 1);
    }
};
class Variant2 {
public:
    typedef size_t* argType;

    static void bar(argType i) {
        std::cout << (*i - 1);
    }
};

template <typename T>
void foo(typename T::argType x)
{
    T::bar(x);
}

//usage
size_t a = 1;
int x = 1;

foo<Variant1>(&a);
foo<Variant2>(&b);
```

Comment: I can't figure out why when someone starts their original question with "I know I cannot use a namespace as a template parameter." another person would start their response with "Namespace can't be a template parameter".