# Template functions using namespace as parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

For performance reasons, I have to make my own classes of vectors, matrixes, tensors, etc, with explicit operations. Since I only work with 2D or 3D dimensions, I defined the classes using namespaces for each dimensions. This is a simple draft of the code:

```
namespace Dim2 {
    class Vec {
        public:
        double components[2];
    };
    
    class Mat {
        public:
        double components[2][2];
    };
}

namespace Dim3 {
    class Vec {
        public:
        double components[3];
    };
    
    class Mat {
        public:
        double components[3][3];
    };
}
```

So if I need, for instance, a 3D vector, I call `Dim3::Vec newVec;`, and I can perform operations which are optimized for 3 dimensions.

Now, let's say I want to write a generic function using templates like this:

```
template<typename Vec, typename Mat>
void doSomething()
{
    Vec v;
    Mat m;
    // Perform operations
}
```

That way, if I want to use 2D vectors, I call `doSomething<Dim2::Vec, Dim2::Mat>();`, and for 3D vectors: `doSomething<Dim3::Vec, Dim3::Mat>();`.

This solution is also addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612759/alternative-to-using-namespace-as-template-parameter), and works fine. The problem is... the 'real' code will have not only vectors and matrixes, but countless other structures: third order tensors, fourth order tensors, symmetric matrixes, etc. If I use all of it in the function, the call would be something like this:

```
doSomething<Dim2::Vec, Dim2::Mat, Dim3::Tensor3, Dim3::Tensor4, Dim4:: SymMat, ...>();
```

which is too extensive (and ugly).

In order to make that short, what I really wanted to do is to make the namespace as template parameter. Something like this:

```
template<typename Dim>
void doSomething()
{
    Dim::Vec v;
    Dim::Mat m;
    Dim::Tensor3 t3;
    Dim::Tensor4 t4;
    Dim::SymMat symMat;
    // Perform operations
}
```

That way, the function call would be simple as `doSomething<Dim2>();` or `doSomething<Dim3>();`.

However, doing that gives me a compiler error, since C++ won't let namespaces as templates parameters. I tried to make the same thing using nested classes (i.e., `Dim2` and `Dim3` as classes, instead of namespaces), but I still got compiler errors.

What can I do in order to perform what I want? Do you guys have any alternatives?

Thanks in advance, and sorry about any english mistake.

Comment: As a bit of a kluge, you can make a `struct Dim3_ns { using Vec = Dim3::Vec; /*et cetera*/ };` and then use `doSomething<Dim3_ns>() { ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use type traits-like helper `struct`s to reduce the number of arguments used to call `doSomething()`.

```
namespace Dim2 {

    class Vec {
        public:
        double components[2];
    };
    
    class Mat {
        public:
        double components[2][2];
    };

   struct Chooser
   {
      using Vec = Vec;
      using Mat = Mat;
   };
}

namespace Dim3 {
    class Vec {
        public:
        double components[3];
    };
    
    class Mat {
        public:
        double components[3][3];
    };

   struct Chooser
   {
      using Vec = Vec;
      using Mat = Mat;
   };
}

template <typename Chooser>
void doSomething()
{
   using Vec = typename Chooser::Vec;
   using Mat = typename Chooser::Mat;

   Vec v1;
   Mat m1;
}

int main()
{
   doSomething<Dim2::Chooser>();
   doSomething<Dim3::Chooser>();
}
```

Comment: Looks nice, thank you very much! But what if I want, for instance, `Vec` to be parameter of the function ? Like `void doSomething(Vec v1)`?

Comment: @PericlesCarvalho, a function overload would work for that.